# Pull out values and associated strings of at least a certain value

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write code to pull out of a vector of data, 1x1000, the values that are a fold change of 2 or more. A fold change of 2 is equivalent to -1. I want to pull out the names of my genes (coded in vector C) and the values (coded in vector fcsites). This is what I have come up with so far but one of my issues is that I don't know what to specify as the length of the new vector. Does anyone know a better way to approach this?

```
atleast = {C,fcsites}
Z = zeros(length(C),1);
for i2=1:length(C)
Z(i2)=C(fcsites<=-1);
end
```

I get the error:

```
atleast = 

    {602x1 cell}    [602x1 double]

The following error occurred converting from cell to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

Comment: I don't think this question can be adequately answered without a specific example of what values are stored `C` and `fcsites`.

Comment: C is basically composed of gene names like: 
    'NM_017590'
    'NM_017612'
    'NM_017671'
(all in one column)
And fcsites is composed of values like: 
 0.6668
    0.4640
    1.1355
    0.6712
    0.0471
    0.9276
    1.6013
(all in one column)

C and fcsites are the same size .. ie one gene for every value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the desired elements in `fcsites`, and use their corresponding indices as a subscript for `C`:

```
idx = (fcsites <= -1);
X = C(idx)
```

or shorter:

```
X = C(fcsites <= -1)
```

Now `X` contains all the names from `C` that correspond to values in `fcsites` that are less than or equal to -1.